# Throttle middleware is not working for unauthenticated users when used with auth:sanctum middleware

Tags: laravel

I would like to protect my Laravel API from brute force attacks of unauthenticated users trying to guess the authentication token. I used the throttle middleware but I can't make it work.

First I tried this to allow 5 guest request per minute on the resource but it is not working:

```
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum','throttle:5|60,1'])->group(function () {
  Route::apiResource('company.vehicles', VehicleController::class); 
});
```

Then I tried having the throttle middleware first, but it is also not working

```
Route::middleware(['throttle:5|60,1'])->group(function () {
    Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum','throttle:5|60,1'])->group(function () {
        Route::apiResource('company.vehicles', VehicleController::class);
    });
});
```

What should I do to make it work?

Comment: I suggest putting some debug statements inside the throttle middleware. I have no clue why this would happen.

Comment: In debugging looks like the auth middleware runs before throttle middleware. But if I make the throttle middleware execute before auth middleware then the throttle middleware will never now if the user is guest or authenticated.

Comment: that sounds about right; you can change the way the throttle middleware operates though, you can for instance rate limit on IP only. Not sure what the current implementation is. Some of it is described here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#rate-limiting

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what you're trying to do.. Sanctum will throttle your login attempts by default. If you're not authenticated you will never hit the routes that are using sanctum's middleware. So throttling attempts to routes behind sanctum's middleware doesn't make sense.

Comment: @NICO Calling a route protected with sanctum middleware requires the Authentication header to be set with the user token. If that token does not exist, sanctum authentication system returns 401 Unauthorized. A malicious user can brute force the route, trying random tokens until he receives 200 OK. Theres is no rate limiting at all until authentication. Check it if you have an api to test. Laravel will allow you to hit the route for ever. So I am trying to find out how to apply rate limiting to this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using the RateLimiter in your Authenticate middleware is an option?

In app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter;

class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    protected function authenticate($request, array $guards)
    {
        // Request guarded by sanctum?
        $guardedBySanctum = in_array('sanctum', $guards);
        
        // If the request is guarded by sanctum
        // and there were to many attempts (5)
        // throw an exception 
        if ($guardedBySanctum && RateLimiter::tooManyAttempts('api', 5)) {
            throw new AuthenticationException(
                'Too many requests. Retry in ' . RateLimiter::availableIn('api') . ' seconds'
            );       
        }
        
        if (empty($guards)) {
            $guards = [null];
        }

        foreach ($guards as $guard) {
            if ($this->auth->guard($guard)->check()) {
                return $this->auth->shouldUse($guard);
            }
        }
        
        // User is unauthenticated
        // If the request is guarded by sanctum...
        if ($guardedBySanctum) {
            // ...hit the rate limiter
            RateLimiter::hit('api');
        }

        $this->unauthenticated($request, $guards);
    }

    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string|null
     */
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('login');
        }
    }
}
```